# OS Capitan freetds.conf directory issue

Tags: sql-server, macos, t-sql, osx-elcapitan, freetds

I'm trying to connect with a SQL Server from *OS Capitan's* console, I installed *FreeTDS* with `brew install homebrew/versions/freetds091` and edited the file `/usr/local/Cellar/freetds091/0.91.112/etc`

```
# A typical Microsoft server
[egServer70]
host = myhost.domain.com 
port = 1433
tds version = 7.0
```

Then, when I try to connect `with tsql -S myhost.domain.com -U user -P password` and I get the following error:

> ```
> locale is "C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C"
> locale charset is "UTF-8"
> using default charset "UTF-8"
> 75Error 20009 (severity 9):   Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist     OS error 60, "Operation timed out"
> There was a problem connecting to the server
> ```

When I execute `tsql -C`, I get:

> ```
> Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
>                         Version: freetds v0.91
>          freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/php5/etc
>  MS db-lib source compatibility: yes
>     Sybase binary compatibility: no
>                   Thread safety: yes
>                   iconv library: yes
>                     TDS version: 5.0
>                           iODBC: no
>                        unixodbc: no
>           SSPI "trusted" logins: no
>                        Kerberos: no
> ```

But there's no freetds.conf file in /usr/local/php5/etc, ¿Is there a way to change the route to freetds.conf file? I have tried uninstalling *FreeTDS* with `brew uninstall freetds` but when I type `tsql -C` I still having the same response.

I check my phpinfo() and maybe this it's generating conflicts

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this, but the easiest is to put a `.freetds.conf` in your home directory. On a Mac, that'd be `/Users/username/.freetds.conf`.

It will be read *before* the system wide configuration if it exists. Reference: http://www.freetds.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm